# mongodb query to lithium command

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb, lithium

```
db.users.aggregate(
    {$match : 
        {"_id" : ObjectId("50f69176904e1d66affec20d")}
    }, 
    {$unwind : "$connections"}, 
    {$match : 
        {$or : [
            {"connections.users" : {$exists : false}}, 
            {"connections.users.id" : "50f651b8b58bba7fbec2f223"}
        ]}},
    {$group : {_id : "$connections.group"}}
)
```

Here I am finding the group names in which specific user exists. I am getting the correct result in mongodb shell. Now I have to use it in the lithium framework. Please help me with the command.
For collection structure, see this link : http://pastebin.com/P8uMw9cj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read Tom Maiaroto's article ["MongoDB Aggregation of all Shapes and Sizes"](http://sphere.orchestra.io/p/Li3-Advent-Day-7)

It covers Map/Reduce, Grouping and The New Aggregation Framework

Comment: This no longer exists sadly. The basic idea is:  Model::connection()->connection->selectCollection('collectionName')->aggregate();   

Lithium doesn't hide anything from you and you are able to get down to the core Mongo PHP extension classes. Simply reference php.net and Mongo documentation from there based on the command or query you want to make.

Comment: Also note that you can get the collection name with: Model::meta('source') so you don't need to put in a string there manually in case of change, re-usability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can run arbitrary commands like this:

```
$files = Files::connection()->connection->command(array("geoNear" => "fs.files", "near" => $coords, "maxDistance" => 1));
```

You would use Users::connection() obviously, but there are also some improvements in aggregation being worked on, though not sure if they are in the master branch.

You can also see a demo app with aggregation here: https://github.com/jmikola/li3-mongodb-aggregation-demo/blob/master/app/controllers/DemoController.php that should help you get going.

Comment: This is a better answer given the link above has been removed. Note that you may need to use selectCollection() unless you wanted to run a command on the entire database (which is fine, you'd specify the collection elsewhere in the command options).